# Netflix keystrokes ignored

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, netflix

I read on this site that some keystrokes can be used to control a Netflix streaming movie, but they do not work for me. **All** keystrokes are ignored once the movie begins and I can only go into full screen mode by mouse clicking the button. **F** and **SpaceBar** are ignored.

Same results on a MacBook Pro using Safari and a MacBook Pro running Windows XP using a Firefox browser.

What could be wrong?